# PHP replace multiline string

Tags: php

I have a multiline string like the following (in PHP):

```
ABCDEF
Colore lato A: NO
Colore lato B: Colore lato B (+3,00)
Colore lato C: NO
Stampa lato A: Stampa lato A (+7,00)
Stampa lato B: NO
Stampa lato C: NO
blablabla
blablabla
```

basically I would like to make these changes:

- Remove all lines starting with 'Colore' or 'Stampa' and end with 'NO'
- Remove the part before ":" lines starting with 'Colore' or 'Stampa'

then the result I would like is the following:

```
ABCDEF
Colore lato B (+3,00)
Stampa lato A (+7,00)
blablabla
blablabla
```

For various reasons I can not turn it into array and modify it.

I use regular expressions but I have not found the correct one, you have some idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Whatever reason you have for not turning it into an array is probably wrong.

Comment: I'm 99% sure I have seen this exact same question earlier. The dubious sentence about the requirement of not being able to turn it into an array gave you away.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = preg_replace('/(' . PHP_EOL . ')?^(Colore|Stampa).*NO|^(Colore|Stampa).*:\s*/m', '', $string);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/p4998X)

Comment: it doesn't work, this is the result of your command
ABCDEF
blablabla
blablabla

Comment: probably the character for new line '\n' don't work. this is probably the reason why I can not turn the string into array

Comment: Try it now with PHP_EOL

Comment: nothing, don't work, in this case I have the same string

Comment: Just realized that `PHP_EOL` needs parentheses around it in case it's multiple characters. What newline sequence do you actually have in your strings?

Comment: nothing, i have the same string, there is a way to identify the end of line characters in a string?

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I don't know what could be different in your strings. Where does the string come from in the first place?

Comment: I'd love to know! , I still find myself in the web page, I'm not generating it!

Comment: I don't know joomla, so I don't know if that makes a difference. Is it getting it from a database? Please show your code that's not working.

Comment: the string is set by this command: $stringa = $product['product_name'] . $product['product_attributes'];